# How to create regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse the following string format:

```
property1 value1
property2 value2
property3 val.ue3
```

where the left word is the property and the following word is its value.
The value should be trimmed at (`\n`, `\r`, ).

I am using the following code:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(string.Format("{0}\\s\\w+", propertyName));
string Val = reg.Match(str).Value;
```

but it has a few issues, and I am having a hard time trying to solve them:

- if the value has a `.`, it trims the string there (e.g. for `property3` it returns `val` but it should return `val.ue3`)
- it doesn't trim the value in a new line or a space (sometime it returns `value2\r`)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: it should return **value3** or **val.ue3**? do you want to avoid any puntuation?

Comment: @Gianmarco good catch, updated the question to what i expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this

```
Regex reg = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}\s+[^\r\n]+", propertyName));
```

---

So,if you have a list of propertyNames

```
 var output=propertyNames.Select(x=>
            new{
               PropertyName=x,
               Value=Regex.Match(input,string.Format(@"(?<={0}\s+)[^\r\n]+",x))
                          .Value
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

> if the value has a "." it trims the string there (i.e for property3 it returns val but it should return value3)

That's because `\\w+` matches alphanumeric characters and underscore, it doesn't match dot characters `.`.

> it doesn't trim the value in a new line or a space (sometime it returns - "value2\r")

I can see how this might be happening because as I said above a `\\w+` matches word characters so once it spots any other character it stops matching.

A better regex:

Since the name of the property is passed in, we have one task left and that is to match the value, since values are always to end with a newline `\n`, carriage return `\r` or dots `.` then we could match one or more characters that are neither of those to capture the value, something like this:

```
{0}\\s*([^\\r\\n ]+)
               ^^
          There is a space here, don't forget it
```

Notice there is a single space  after the `\\n` in the character class above.

[RegexHero Demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=a18f4375-bcfc-4c6c-97fa-d1052afd5078)

Comment: *“I can see how this might be happening.”* How? Could you explain?

Comment: @Gianmarco Thank you for notifying me, answer modified accordingly.

Comment: @minitech OK I will modify my answer.

Comment: @minitech I have explained my thought, please review.

Comment: @Sniffer: That doesn’t make sense. `\w+` is the last part of the match. `\w` shouldn’t match `\r`.

Comment: I got this exception when i tried it (ArgumentException) - parsing "Active\s*+[^\r\n.]+" - Nested quantifier +.

Comment: @Yosi Sorry for this one, I though this was java, you will have to remove the `+` from `\s*+`, I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: @minitech I think that you and I agree on the same thing so what is the problem ?

Comment: According to @Yosi, the problem is that sometimes it matches a trailing `\r`. At least, that’s how I interpreted it. Doesn’t really matter.

Comment: @Yosi Well this is pretty weird, something is not right with what you are doing. I have added a demo so you can see that it actually works.

Comment: @Sniffer: Nobody downvoted you; you were unupvoted. (No, I have no idea why)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be more appropriate to put your string into a dictionary and use that.

```
var dict =
    str.Split(new char[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] {' '}, 2))
       .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);

string val = dict[propertyName];
```

[Hey, it works!](http://ideone.com/XFZliT)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need a regular expression for that. The `Split` method should cut the mustard:

```
string input = 
@"property1 value1 
property2 value2 
property3 val.ue3";
IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> result =
    (from line in input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    let parts = line.Split(' ')
    where parts.Length > 1
    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(parts[0], parts[1])).ToList();
```

and now you could use the result which will contain the key value pairs:

```
property1: value1
property2: value2
property3: val.ue3
```

Answer (score 0):

`\w` matches any letter, digit or underscore (see [Word Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter) for the precise definition), but it does not match a literal `.`. For that you can use a character class, like  `[\w.]`.

Also, you really should use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) if you're constructing the pattern from other strings like this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}\s[\w.]+", Regex.Escape(propertyName)));
string Val = reg.Match(str).Value;
```

Or possibly dispense with the `string.Format`:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(Regex.Escape(propertyName) + @"\s[\w.]+");
string Val = reg.Match(str).Value;
```

Note the use of `@` to create a verbatim [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) literal. This generally makes regular expressions easier to read because you don't need to escape `\` in the pattern.